# Execute JavaScript function when clicking on ASP.NET button

Tags: asp.net

I have a button:

```
<asp:Button
    runat="server"
    ID="btNew"
    OnClick="ButtonNew_Click"
    Text="New" />
```

I have the OnClick method:

```
protected void ButtonNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

On the same page (.aspx), I have a JavaScript function:

```
function MyCheck()
{
    // Return true or false
}
```

I'd like when I click on the button to execute the JavaScript function (`MyCheck()`). If true, execute `ButtonNew_Click()`. If false, don't execute `ButtonNew_Click()`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
function clientfunction()
{
    // Do the client side validations here.

    // Now call the server side button event explicitly
    __doPostBack('OnClick','button_ID');
}
```

In button onclientclick, call the function clientfunction():

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btNew" OnClick="ButtonNew_Click" Text="New" onclientclick="clientfunction()"/>
```

Comment: You can just do `return true` or `false`, no need to call __doPostBack

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
btNew.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return MyCheck();");
```

Comment: That's call the javascript function but I'd like when the method return false NOT execute `ButtonNew_Click`

Comment: then u need to do something in javascript code ... after checking the conditions call method from javascript

Comment: it's `btNew.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return MyCheck();");` edit your answer

Answer (score -1):

USE [OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx)

```
OnClientClick=" MyCheck"
```

if your method will return false then ButtonNew_Click will not get called.

Answer (score -1):

Server-side code:

```
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace count
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = "button clicked";
        }
    }
}
```

Client side:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs"      Inherits="count.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function aa() {
                return true;
            }            
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">            
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="return aa()" Text="Button" />
            <p>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

If in function aa() JavaScript you will return false; it will not execute server-side code.